# change background color of a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sidebar and script that I use to change the background links when is clicked by adding a class. But the class of the other links are not removed and the link doesn't work.

```js
$('#mianav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('miaactive').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('miaactive');
  localStorage.setItem('target', $(this).data("target"));
});
var target = localStorage.getItem('target');
!target || $('a[data-target="' + target +  '"]').addClass('miaactive').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('miaactive');
```

```html
<nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
  <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
    <div class="nav" id="mianav">
      <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
        Dashboard
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'agenda' %}">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></div>
        Agenda
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-database"></i></div>
        CRUD App
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></div>
        File Upload
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullseye"></i></div>
        Ajax Crud
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Not true that are not solutions for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not have a data-target on any link
2. The links do not work because of the preventDefault, which is what one uses to stop a link from following the href
3. The navigation to the links is very prone to errors and will fail if you move the links anywhere or add a container in the navigation

Here is a working version with very simplified script once you add data-target to the links

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ocgjmk4f/

I cannot post a working version here since SO does not support localStorage

```js
const $links = $('#mianav a.nav-link').click(function(e) { console.log($(this).data("target"))
  $links.not(this).removeClass('miaactive');
  $(this).addClass('miaactive');
  localStorage.setItem('target', $(this).data("target"));
});
var target = localStorage.getItem('target');
$links.removeClass('miaactive');
if (target) $(`#mianav a[data-target="${target}"]`).click();
```

Comment: You need `data-target`, not `target`